# How would I extend this input validation?

Tags: jquery

I'm collecting form input values and using localstorage to save them.

Here's the code that checks one of the inputs and performs what I want—but for just one input:

```
$('#refresh').click(function() {
    if (localStorage['t'] == null || localStorage['t'].length == 0) {
        $("input#t").css("background-color", "yellow");
        return;
    }
    save_data()
    window.location = 't4.html';
});
```

​
So, I will have more input values (t, t1, t2 ...) and would like to highlight any/all of the empty ones as performed in the sample. A validation plugin seems unnecessary since this is the only place validation will be needed. Plus, I prefer not to check upon input entry but only when `#refresh.click` is performed so there is only one "nag" for the user.

Thanks from the newbie for your help!

**UPDATE:** `.each` was suggested but suspect there must be a better way than this:

```
  $('#refresh').click(function () {

      $("input").each(function (i) {

        if(localStorage['t'] == null || localStorage['t'].length == 0 ) {
        $("input#t").css("background-color","yellow");
        return;
        } 

        if(localStorage['t1'] == null || localStorage['t1'].length == 0 ) {
        $("input#t1").css("background-color","yellow");
        return;
        }

        if(localStorage['t2'] == null || localStorage['t2'].length == 0 ) {
        $("input#t2").css("background-color","yellow");
        return;
        }

        if(localStorage['t3'] == null || localStorage['t3'].length == 0 ) {
        $("input#t3").css("background-color","yellow");
        return;
        }

        else {

        save_data()

        window.location = 't4.html';
        }
      });
    });
```

Comment: Validation plugins save work and make your validation solid, why avoid?

Comment: @Kos Seems like overkill to load a full-featured validation script for a single validation instance. Plus, the validation plugins I've seen seem to be designed to check individual inputs upon entry rather than what I noted above about a one-time "nag".

Answer (score 1):

you can iterate over each element using jQuery's .each() :)

[.each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/)

Comment: How would you propose to declare the localstorage vars for the .each?